# how to change input text placeholder color if using foundation

Tags: css, forms, zurb-foundation, placeholder

I am having trouble changing the placeholder text color in a form text box. I'm using zurb's foundation, and that may be to blame. The placeholder text default color is just too light. I'm viewing the page in Chrome.

Here is my code. Does anyone know how to change the placeholder text color under these circumstances, please?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
input::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: #ff0000;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #ff0000;
}
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #ff0000;
   opacity:  1;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #ff0000;
   opacity:  1;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #ff0000;
}
input::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
   color:    #ff0000;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/foundation-6.2/css/foundation.css" />

    <!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmSearchAddress" method="post">

                    <div class="row">

                    <div class="large-4 columns">

                        <input type="text" placeholder="Street number" name="street_number" required/>
                        <div class="error">No results found.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-6 columns">  
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Street name" name="street_name" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-2 columns">  
                        <input class="" type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch">
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
<script src="../includes/foundation-6.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS is probably overwritten by ZurbFoundation CSS, as you set your own styles before loading ZurbFoundation CSS. Try to switch the order of your used CSS and it should work.

Unline inline style like `<div style="color:red">`, defining an external CSS with `<link>` or using `<style>` makes no difference in specificity or precedence.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/foundation-6.2/css/foundation.css" />

<style>
input::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: #ff0000;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #ff0000;
}
input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #ff0000;
   opacity:  1;
}
input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #ff0000;
   opacity:  1;
}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #ff0000;
}
input::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
   color:    #ff0000;
}
</style>

    <!--<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmSearchAddress" method="post">

                    <div class="row">

                    <div class="large-4 columns">

                        <input type="text" placeholder="Street number" name="street_number" required/>
                        <div class="error">No results found.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-6 columns">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Street name" name="street_name" required/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-2 columns">
                        <input class="" type="submit" value="Search" id="btnSearch">
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </form>
<script src="../includes/foundation-6.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
      $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Woo hoo! Thank you, @marvhock!